# Delete Duplicate Header

Tags: vba, header, duplicates

im new to vba, I want to have duplicate column header removed.

example:
A1:Year A2:2002 A3:2005 A4:2012 A5:Year A6:2005 A7:Year
B1:Department B2:Sales B3:Marketing B4:HR B5:Department B6:Marketing B7:Department
C1:Cost C2:111 C3:23784 C4:1234 C5:Cost C6:5737 C7:Cost

In this example, I want to keep everything except the duplicate Headers (Row5 & 7 here), these should be deleted so in the end it will look like this:

A1:Year A2:2002 A3:2005 A4:2012 A5:2005 
B1:Department B2:Sales B3:Marketing B4:HR B5:Marketing 
C1:Cost C2:111 C3:23784 C4:1234 C5:5737

I dont know in which row the duplicate headers will be, also i dont know when the row ends. I tried to work with find and lastrow

```
Option Explicit

 Sub rh()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Dup As Integer
    Dim Lastrow As Integer

On Error Resume Next

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("TESTSHEET")

Dup = ws.Range("A2:C" & Lastrow).Find("Year", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Columns

ws.Select
Columns(Dup).Select
Selection.Delete

End Sub
```

This didnt work for me, it didnt delete the rows in which duplicate Headers have been found

Comment: Have you tried `RemoveDuplicates`

Comment: Yes, but i want to delete only duplicate header, and removeduplicate also removes duplicate data, like "2013" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Excel Way

There's no need to write VBA code to do this, just use the Excel function **Remove Duplicates**. Here's how to do it:

1. Select the range of cells that has duplicate values you want to remove.
2. Click **Data > Remove Duplicates**, and then Under **Columns**, check or uncheck the columns where you want to remove the duplicates. 
    
   [image]
3. For example, in this worksheet, the Name column has duplicates that I want to delete.

[image]

And after deleting duplicates from Name Column, that's how it looks:

[image]

---

### The VBA Way

If you must use VBA to achieve this, then you can use the `RemoveDuplicates` function:

> **With Headers**

```
Sub sbRemoveDuplicatesSpecificWithHeaders()
   Range("A1:D10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:= xlYes 
End Sub
```

---

> **Without Headers**

```
Sub sbRemoveDuplicatesSpecificWithNoHeaders()
   Range("A1:D10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:= xlNo
End Sub
```

---

### Removing duplicate headers

In this particular case, there are multiple headers that repeat themselves with no particular pattern. If you want to eliminate them, use the following code:

```
Sub removeDuplicates()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim index As Long
    Dim header As String

    header = Range("A1").Value
    lrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    For index = 2 To lrow
        If Range("A" & index).Value = header Then Rows(index).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: because of what appears to be a bug in Excel, removing duplicates will honor wildcard characters in the data, so `*123` will be considered a duplicate of `ABC123`. Depending on the actual data, there might therefore still be a case for doing it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: thanks for the answer louis and Mathieu, i need to do this with VBA. unfortunately your soultion didnt work out for me, since i only want duplicated headers to be deleted and not duplicate data. its a report i get on regular basis so i dont know how many datarows there are and i also dont know in which rows the duplicate headers are

Comment: @croyx By "removing duplicate headers" you mean you need to remove a Column, to speak in Excel language?

Comment: @louis i have written an example in starting post, i do NOT want to remove columns, i want to have all rows removed where the headers appear again, in this case Row 5 and Row 7 because the headers appear again. imagine i get every month a report with the same structure, you merge these 12 monthly reports into 1 report for a year. in this report you are gonna have 12 headers in the dataset included, but the goal is to have at the end only 1 header at the top and duplicate headers removed

Comment: @croyx Ok, I've updated the code to include your particular case. Let me know if that solved the issue for you.